# Cannot install Ruby with homebrew

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm trying to install Ruby using Homebrew. When I run `brew install ruby` I get

```
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using 'brew postinstall ruby'
```

And when I try that it says

```
Error: Directory not empty - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_1/lib/ruby/gems
```

So I tried deleting the contents of that folder and now it says

```
Error: undefined method `symlink' for #<Pathname:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_1/lib/ruby/gems>
```

Does anyone know why this happening?

Comment: Currently being addressed here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29982

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can track the issue at [ruby: Fix undefined method and directory not empty errors #29986](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/29986) or follow the discussion [link](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29982)